# NuGet: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, visual-studio-2017

When I try to add a new package with NuGet I get the error

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

I've checked several posts about this and tried alot of solutions but can't seem to find the issue. It might be worthing noting that I moved and renamed my project at some point and the copy I left behind still functions with NuGet packages.

After looking into it some more I found this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>      at EnvDTE.SourceControl.CheckOutItem(String ItemName)

What I've tried already:

- Deleting the **user.csproj** and/or **.suo**
- Checking all project references and if they are located correctly
- Deleting Temp files
- Deleting bin & obj folders
- Deleting the ProjectTemplatesCache
- Checking the project web properties
- Restarting VS, cleaning and rebuilding the project (always run in
  admin).
- Deleting the ComponentModelCache
- Deleting packages folder content and restoring NuGet packages in
  solution.
- Check-in all pending changes to version control before attempting to
  add a new NuGet package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking in all pending changes and then performing a 'check-out for edit now' did the trick.

Answer (score 14):

I just had this 01.08.2019 with both Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2017. I've tried the following solutions which **did not work**:

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeocs/en-US/4eea5785-0a83-4389-89e3-209a5a4432c0/referencemanagerpackage-fails-to-install-vs-2017-community-edition?forum=vssetup
2. [Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component on Add Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037679/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-on-add-ref)

What worked for me is simply deleting the `.vs` folder and also deleting everything from the packages folder of the solution I was using. Then I ran `Restore NuGet Packages` on the solution level.

Comment: Wasted 2 days on this...This was the only thing that worked for me. `Update-Package -reinstall` was the command. It then did complain that it didn't even recognise the `ActionResult`-type (which is pretty fundamental in asp.net), but prompted me to download System.Web.Mvc via nuget.

Comment: thanks...this is helpful for me in visual studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a log4net version on a build server. After backing up the local source folder I removed it, then started up visual studio, went to the Source Control Explorer, found my solution and went to Check out for Edit.

[image: check out for edit]

Once I had a new local copy of latest version, had to go to the directory on disk and replace the log4net package.

[image: directory]

Then go back to visual studio, and build the solution, which built ok now. Then check everything in again, and the build server was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

It can be happen when you create a Project in upper version **Visual Studio** and working in lower version **Visual Studio**.

Check which version **Visual Studio** you create your project and now working in which version **Visual studio**.

Try it on latest version **Visual Studio**.