# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component on Add Reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In VS-2017, on clicking "Add Reference" I am getting an error:

```
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."
```

due to which I am unable to

1. add any reference and
2. update my database through DB_First Approach

This issue started occuring after the last update of Windows.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me

1. Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 with admin privileges
2. Type into the the Developer Command Prompt

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

Your path may differ so check

3. Type into Developer Command Prompt

gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll

It should rebuild and you may now add references!

Comment: I have this problem in VS2022 now and there is no such directory \\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\ or even \PublicAssemblies\ in any of subdirectories :(

Answer (score 3):

This link helped me a lot:

[Add a reference raise error: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/260196/add-a-reference-raise-error-error-hresult-e-fail-h.html)

> Steps:
>
> 1. Open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" as Admin
> 2. CD
>    into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>    Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"
> 3. Run "gacutil
>    -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll"  After that close and reopen "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" as Admin
> 4. cd
>    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1
>    Tools\x64"
> 5. Run -> gacutil.exe /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>    Visual
>    Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll"
>
>    ```
>    Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility. Version 4.0.30319.0
>    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
>    Assembly successfully added to the cache
>    ```
>
> Restarting your PC will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

My issue happened when I tried to open newly cloned solution (that was previously developed in VS2019) in VS2022 and got lots of issues with missing references, most of them failing on `AutoMapper` that was giving the above error. I copied the projects that had problem to build from a solution backup, rebuilt and all started working in VS2022.

Answer (score 1):

For VS Enterprise it works (run in developer command prompt):
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.1 Tools\x64>gacutil.exe /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Error message UPON TRYING TO EDIT A USER CONTROL [SHIFT+F7].

I tried all previous answers and nothing helped.

In my case I had .cs files used by both, .Net, and .Net Framework [added as reference only].
Only after unloading the .Net Framework from solution - I managed to edit the .Net UI.